# error while implementing drop function in a gam model

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I built my gam model using the `mgcv` package

```
gam1<-gam(rainfed ~ s(defjjas) + s(defjune) + s(defon) + s(pepjjas)+ s(pepon) + s(precon), family =binomial,data=data)
```

I want to built a minimum adequate model i.e. remove those variables which do not have any explanatory power. This I do using the `drop` function:

```
drop1(gam1,test = "Chi")
```

However, this gives me an errow which says:

```
Error in glm.control(nthreads = 1, irls.reg = 0, epsilon = 1e-07, maxit = 200,  : 
unused arguments (nthreads = 1, irls.reg = 0, mgcv.tol = 1e-07, mgcv.half = 
15, rank.tol = 1.49011611938477e-08, nlm = list(ndigit = 7, gradtol = 1e-06,
stepmax = 2, steptol = 1e-04, iterlim = 200, check.analyticals = FALSE), optim
= list(factr = 1e+07), newton = list(conv.tol = 1e-06, maxNstep = 5,    
maxSstep = 2, maxHalf = 30, use.svd = FALSE), outerPIsteps = 0, idLinksBases    
= TRUE, scalePenalty = TRUE, keepData = FALSE, scale.est = "pearson")
```

Could anyone tell me what this error means and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you set `select = TRUE` in your `gam` call instead? I don't think `drop1` can be used with a `gam` model. Note that the documentation of `anova.gam` says that its "interpretation is analogous to `drop1`" since "Wald tests of the significance of each parametric and smooth term are performed".